# How to print the first dynamic string in a json decoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to print out the worker names from the following out put

```js
{
   "result":{
      "addr":"54GaFN8vWMgJ",
      "workers":[
         [
            "worker1", <-- print out dynamic worker names
            {
               "a":"0.67"
            },
            14,
            1,
            "200000",
            0,
            22
         ],
         [
            "worker2", <-- print out dynamic worker names 
            {
               "a":"1972.88"
            },
            9,
            1,
            "2048",
            0,
            24
         ]
      ],
      "algo":-1
   },
   "method":"stats.provider.workers"
}
```

so far I have tried using the following:

```js
$worker_names = json_decode($get_data, true);
$i = 0;
foreach ($worker_names['result']['workers'] as $key => $value) {
  print "<td>".$value[$i++]."</td>";
 }
```

This kind of works as it display the first worker name with the rest of the contents in the array.

Is there a better way to perhaps print just the first string in the array, which is the worker names ?

output should display :

`worker1
worker2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you isolate the `workers` element of the JSON object, you'll have an array you can iterate through. Here is a way to print the worker names:

```
$data = json_decode($get_data);
$workers = $data->result->workers;
foreach ($workers AS $worker) {
    print($worker[0].'<br>');
}
```

Output:

```
worker1
worker2
```

Comment: Thanks, that works to grab the worker names. how would I go about selecting say the last output in the array ?

Comment: awesome, I have been messing around trying to get the contents in "a" and "rs" using this method `$workers[count($workers)-1]` and I'm not sure if its efficient as the "rs" is dynamic and only displays when there is a rejected speed

Answer (score 1):

don't increment the $i inside the foreach loop or else set index value as 0

you try this:

```
foreach ($worker_names['result']['workers'] as $key => $value) {
        print "<td>".$value[0]."</td>";
    }
```

Comment: this works, although when I try to select the "a" or "rs" it shows a `w` as an output ?

Comment: if you want to select "a" then you need change your code to `print "<td>".$value[1]["a"]."</td>";`